# I was trying to make a chrome extension and Getting localStorage undefined error while using manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, manifest.json

With manifest v2 it is working fine. But with manifest v3 I'm getting error "ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined"

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
var contextMenuItems = {
  "title": 'Add to notepad"',
  "contexts": ["selection"],
  "id": "myContextMenuId"
};
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItems);
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData){
  if(clickData.menuItemId == "myContextMenuId" && clickData.selectionText){
   localStorage.setItem("text", "clickData.selectionText");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The background script in ManifestV3 is a `service worker` now so it can't access stuff exposed only on `window` like HTML5 localStorage or DOM. By the way, service workers don't have `window`, their global context is `self` or `globalThis`.

The solution is to switch to [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). It's an entirely different storage available in all extension contexts including content scripts. Note that a) it's asynchronous so the usage is different and b) it doesn't currently return a Promise due to a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1197387) so you can't `await` it. Until it's fixed, use the callback version shown in the documentation.

Storing:

```js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(info => {
  if (info.menuItemId == 'myContextMenuId' && info.selectionText) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({text: info.selectionText});
  }
});
```

Reading in popup:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get('text', ({text}) => {
  // the callback runs asynchronously so you should use the value here
  document.body.prepend(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For Typescript users or if you want to support firefox also then you can use a plugin called as [webextension-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webextension-polyfill)  ,and it is promises based

Code

```
 import browser from "webextension-polyfill";

 browser.storage.local.get(['text']).then((res)=>{
 console.log(res)
});
```